# update friendly NoSQL database

Tags: database, nosql, distributed-system

we are designing a distributed system that needs a highly available key-value store. in this system, we have to store the latest state of client records so they will be updated frequently.
Is there any update-friendly NoSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I would start at Mongo or Redis, there are likely more requirements you have.
And assuming you are not looking at pure open source providers i.e. Couch/Cassandra etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).